# Regular expression to match 7-12 digits; may contain space or hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to solve a PHP regular expression problem for awhile now but I just can't quite get it done.  I need write a regex that will match between 7 and 12 digits (0..9) and there may optionally be either a single hyphen or a single space between adjacent digits.  This is what I have so far...

```
$match1 = preg_match('/^\d[0-9\-\s]{5,10}\d$/', $number);
$match2 = preg_match('/(-\s|\s-|--|\s\s)/', $number);
```

As you can see I have to use two different checks and it still isn't enough for me as I can input this string: "`1-2-3-4-5`" and it will still pass because there are a total of 9 characters but it should fail because there are only 5 digits.

Any help on the matter would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
/^(\d[-\s]?){6,11}\d$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^\d(?:[-\s]?\d){6,11}$/
```

This allows seven to twelve digits that may be separated by a hyphen or a whitespace character.

Comment: +1 putting the single digit first, not last. Is just a personal preference

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:\d[-\s]?){6,11}\d$
```

Comment: Ahh.. you didn't realise that the [-\s] is optional. So I did beat you to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\d([-\s]?\d){6,11}
```