# php regex: phone number 7-12 digits may contain hypen or space

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I tried the solution for phone numbers with 7-12 digits that may contain spaces or hypens in the following link. The first and last character has to be a number.

[Regular expression to match 7-12 digits; may contain space or hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095711/regular-expression-to-match-7-12-digits-may-contain-space-or-hyphen)

However, i'm not understanding the regex well.

```
$phone_pattern="/^\d(?:[-\s]?\d){6,11}$/";
```

what does the ":" mean here?

How is this regex able to exclude the hypens and spaces from the 6 to 11 characters?

Help help is highly appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You have a solution, do you need an explanation of it? Or do you want to match something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a testing engine like regexpal (there are others available also) I frequently use this to test various strings against expressions to make sure they are behaving as expected.

My understanding is that in this case the **:** is not acting alone it is acting in conjunction with the **?**

The **?** in this circumstance does not mean Preceding zero or one times it is a modifier meaning give this group a new meaning which in conjunction with the modifier **:** turn off capture means you want this to be a non capturing group expression.

The effect that this has is that when placing part of an expression inside **()** it by default causes capture but **?:** switches this off.

Thus (?:[-\s]?\d) becomes a non capturing group expression.

Note captured groups are used with back references and most regex engines support up to 9 back references.

So removing capture speeds up the matching process and allows you to elect not to refer back to that group saving one of your 9 references for a group that you really do want to refer back to.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Does that mean space and hypen is not going to be included when verifying the regular expression? only numbers will be verified?

Comment: @vaanipala No the group is still applied in the matching process. But you are unable to back reference that group.

Answer (score 4):

The `:` is part of the `(?: ... )` - which means "non-capturing group" - it groups content but does not create a backreference to it (i.e. $1, $2, etc) like normal grouping does.

In that regex it will match from 6 up to 11 characters, *including* the heiphens and spaces - it meaning something like 12-------34 would match. I suggest using a more strict pattern:

`/^\d{7,12}$/`

This will only match the digits. To allow for heiphens and spaces with this match, but only get the number you want, you can use it like this:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/^\d{7,12}$/';
$string = '123-456 789';
$ignoreCharacters = array(' ', '-');

preg_match($pattern, str_replace($ignoreCharacters, $string);
```

Comment: I have no idea on what is a non-capturing group. I guess I have to read up a lot. Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: You use brackets to capture matches and place them in to "callbacks" - $1, $1, etc. If you want to use brackets without putting them in to callbacks you use (?: ) instead - it groups the same, just doesn't put the reference in to $1, $2, $3 etc :)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the purpose of backreference and non-capturing group? This seems to be advanced regex for me. I'm clueless. I only understand simple regex. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I found this great link http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html that i'm reading up now. I will let u know if I have doubt.

Comment: If you want to apply repetition to a group of rules - i.e to optionally (zero or one times) match a string "Hello" with any number of digits after it, you could first write the regex to match the string: `Hello\d+`, then wrap it in a group so you can add the zero or one repetition `?` character: `(Hello\d+)?`. If you didn't have the brackets, it would only apply the `?` on the `\d+` before it, *not* the whole thing, so you use the brackets to group the content. Grouping with `( .. )` creates a callback (in our case, $1), but if we didn't want to create that $1 backreference we can use `(?: )`

Answer (score 3):

It's understandable how that can be confusing. The `(?: ... )` actually denotes a "non-capturing group," as opposed to the `( ... )`, which is a "capturing group". If you're only testing strings against regexes, not capturing substrings, then the two are effectively the same for your purposes.

It doesn't help that there also exist `(?= ... )`, `(?! ... )`, `(?<= ... )`, `(?<! ... )`, and `(?<foo> ... )`, which all mean different things, too.

A lot to learn, but rewarding for sure!