# javascript regex backrefence

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

This is the continuation of [php regex: phone number 7-12 digits may contain hypen or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704345/php-regex-phone-number-7-12-digits-may-contain-hypen-or-space)

I'm still trying to understand backreferences.  The following is the JavaScript code I came up with to test backreferences.  When I run this code only `null` is being outputted. Where am I going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myRegexFunc()
{   myString="abcabcxabcdefghi";
    patt1=new RegExp("(abc)?\1x\1");
    document.write(patt1.exec(myString));
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myRegexFunc()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\` in the string.

```
patt1 = new RegExp("(abc)?\\1x\\1");
```

Or you could use the regex literal:

```
patt1 = /(abc)?\1x\1/;
```

Comment: Can you tell why why there is a comma followed by "abc"? I thought the result should only be "abcabccxabc". Thank you.

Comment: @vaanipala because the result is an array.

Comment: But there should only be one match for this. I still don't understand about the second "abc" in the output. Please help.