# Match against 1 hyphen per any number of digit groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with some regex to match against 1 hyphen per any number of digit groups. No characters ([a-z][A-Z]).

123-356-129811231235123-1235612346123451235

```
/[^\d-]/g
```

The one above will match the string below, but it will let the following go through:

1223--1235---123123-------

I was looking at the following post [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression) for an answer, but I didn't find anything close.

@Konrad Rudolph gave a good example.

[Regular expression to match 7-12 digits; may contain space or hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095711/regular-expression-to-match-7-12-digits-may-contain-space-or-hyphen)

This tool is useful for me http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Could it ever start with a hyphen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it can't ever start with a hyphen:

```
^\d(-\d|\d)*$
```

broken down:

```
^             # match beginning of line
   \d         # match single digit
   (-\d|\d)+  # match hyphen & digit or just a digit (0 or more times)
$             # match end of line
```

That makes every hyphen *have* to have a digit immediately following it. Keep in mind though, that the following are examples of legal patterns:

```
213-123-12314-234234
1-2-3-4-5-6-7
12234234234
```

[gskinner example](http://regexr.com?341vg)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
^(\d+-)+(\d+)$
```

So it's one or more group(s) of digits followed by hyphen + final group of digits.
Nothing very fancy, but in my tests it matched only when there were hyphen(s) with digits on both sides.